# Copy NSdate Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I am calling one function from another view controller which is passing NSDate object to that function which is another view controller, but At that function passed date is not goin to be assigned/ copying to another local NSDate object.

Here is my code.

```
 - (void)setDefaultCalendarDate:(NSDate *)aDate {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        selectedNSDate = [aDate copy]; 
//selectedNSDate=aDate;
```

How to copy aDate into selectedNSDate? When I take NSlog for it I get null

Comment: How to copy aDate into selectedNSDate? When I take NSlog for it I get null

Comment: When you NSLog aDate, it is null? or when you NSLog selectedNSDate after you copy it, it is null?

Comment: Going out on a limb and guessing that this isn't all of the code. The error probably isn't here. Post all of relevant code, please?

Comment: Yes when I take NSLog for selectedNSDate after copy statement I get null.But when I take log for aDate I get value

Comment: Are you trying to copy the data from aDate so you can change it, or do you just need it, and aren't going to make any modifications to it?

Answer (score 3):

You're almost certainly getting `nil` because `aDate` is already `nil`, so copying it gets you nothing.

Try `NSLog(@"%@", aDate)` -- what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

selectedNSDate = aDate surely?
or if needed selectedNSDate = [aDate retain];

Comment: Yes...but m getting NULL to selectedNSDate

Comment: look at the other answer. If you're setting any object from another, and it's turning out to be nil, it's probably because the object you were setting it with was nil.